# Output Powershell results to individual text documents

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach, exchange-server-2010

I figured this might be an easy answer, but for the life of me I can't suss out why this simple thing seems to be beating me. I am looking to output the results of

```
Get-Mailbox –Server MYserverName | Get-MailboxPermission | FL
```

piped into individual text files for each individual mailbox, with the text file named for the mailbox - e.g. I want to have a folder with the content:

- C:\Example\MailboxUser1.txt
- C:\Example\MailboxUser2.txt
- C:\Example\MailboxUser3.txt

with each containing the mailbox permission results.

I know I can do a foreach loop along the lines of:

```
ForEach-Object {Out-file $_.name}
```

to generate the output files, but I'm not too sure how I would do this in a single step to get the permissions for all my mailboxes into individual files (I know this will give me a lot of text files!)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
$directory = "C:\example\"
$count = 0

Get-Mailbox –Server "MYserverName" | Foreach-Object {
    Get-MailboxPermission | Format-List |
        Out-File (Join-Path $directory "MailboxUser-$(++$count).txt")
}
```

At each pass of the `ForEach-Object` loop (mailbox), a file will be generated with the output of the `Get-MailboxPermission` command.

`++$count` increments the value just before using it (as opposed to `$count++`)

If you prefer to user the `Name` property of the mailbox object to name the files:

```
$directory = "C:\example\"

Get-Mailbox –Server "MYserverName" | Foreach-Object {
    $mailboxName = $_.Name
    Get-MailboxPermission | Format-List |
        Out-File (Join-Path $directory "MailboxUser-$mailboxName.txt")
}
```

Comment: when outputting to a file it is recomended to use `select-object` or nothing at all instead of the `format` commands...this is because of the type of objects created by the `format` commands.

Comment: Thanks all - this did the trick for me nicely - I ended up going a bit simpler though:
    $mailbox = Get-Mailbox
    $mailbox | % { Get-MailboxPermission $_ | FL | Out-file "$_.txt" }

Answer (score -1):

```
Get-Mailbox –Server MYserverName | Get-MailboxPermission | foreach {out-file "$($_.name).txt"}
```

This would be able to get you all the permissions you need IF "name" was the property you were looking at.  I don't work with exchange cmdlets so I don't know if that will count.

Comment: Wouldn't this create a file for each **permission** ?

Comment: depends on what is crossing the pipeline.  Again, I'm not familiar with with how exchange cmdlets works as I am an AD guy myself.  I'm assuming that Get-MailboxPermissions returns an object with user and ACL information, not just ACL information (my interpretation of the OP saying the $_.name for the outfile) This could be totally off but just just my assumption on how POSH works and what I can infer with what the OP put in the initial post.